# making elements of matrix into integers

Tags: matrix

how to make elements in a matrix into integers?

here is my matrix:

```
{{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 
  0., 0., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.,
   0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 
  0., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., -1., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
  0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., -1.}, {0., 0., 
  0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 
  1.}}
```

And I want to convert it to

```
{{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0,...}
```

Comment: `amat // Round` ? where `amat` is your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html).

From the link above you can see in the `>Details` part

```
Rationalize[x,0] converts any inexact number x to rational form.
```

We define your matrix:

```
matrix = {{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0., 0., 
    0., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 
    0., 0., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1., -1., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 
    1., 0., -1., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., -1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
     0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.}};
```

and then we perform

```
matrix // Rationalize[#, 0] &
```

> [image: matrix]

Answer (score 4):

A few other methods

```
mat = {{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {1., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1., -1., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 
   1., 0., 0., 0., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
   0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 
   0., -1., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1., -1., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 
   0., -1., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., -1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
    1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.}};

Clear[results, pairs, methods, timings]
results = {};
pairs = {methods, timings} = {#, First@RepeatedTiming[AppendTo[results, #@mat];]} & /@ {Floor, Ceiling, Round, IntegerPart, Rationalize} // Transpose;
(*Methods and timings*) Grid[Transpose@pairs, Frame -> All]
(*All results are equal*) Equal @@ results
(*Comparison plot*) ListPlot[
 Evaluate@MapThread[Labeled, {Log10@timings, methods}],
 PlotLabel -> "Log10 of method timings",
 Axes -> {False, True},
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic},
 GridLines -> {None, Log10@timings},
 GridLinesStyle -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> Large
]
```

> $ \begin{array}{|c|c|}
>  \hline
>  \text{Floor} & 0.0000378 \\
>  \hline
>  \text{Ceiling} & 0.000050 \\
>  \hline
>  \text{Round} & 0.0000610 \\
>  \hline
>  \text{IntegerPart} & 0.000078 \\
>  \hline
>  \text{Rationalize} & 0.0001 \\
>  \hline
> \end{array} $

> True

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! i learned a lot!